# regression reference group and categorical data

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I'm a new researcher trying to teach myself R. My data covers contaminant concentration (y) in relation to state (OK, NM, TX), month (May, June, July, August), body condition index (continuous), and gender (male/female). I have 97 concentrations in total. I have a working R code for multiple linear regression, AICc, and model averaging (AICcmodavg), but I realized that some of my categorical variable aren't appearing in the initial regression (and, therefore, no where else). Right now, my New Mexico/female/August samples aren't showing up because they are in the reference group/intercept.

```
    datum=read.csv(file.choose())
    #open ContaminantPractice CSV file
    head(datum)
      Contaminant_ppm    State    Sex Month       BCI
    1           0.401 Oklahoma Female   May 0.3226562
    2           0.377 Oklahoma Female   May 0.3308271
    3           0.260 Oklahoma Female   May 0.3587786
    4           0.135 Oklahoma   Male   May 0.3435114
    5           0.181 Oklahoma Female   May 0.3770492
    6           0.220 Oklahoma   Male   May 0.3525180
    #run multiple regression 
    results=lm(Contaminant_ppm~State+Month+Sex+BCI+State*Month*Sex*BCI+State*Month*Sex+State*Month*BCI+State*Sex*BCI+Month*Sex*BCI+State*Month+State*Sex+State*BCI+Month*Sex+Month*BCI+Sex*BCI, data=datum)
    summary(results)
    Call:
    lm(formula = Contaminant_ppm ~ State + Month + Sex + BCI + State * Month *
        Sex * BCI + State * Month * Sex + State * Month * BCI + State *
        Sex * BCI + Month * Sex * BCI + State * Month + State * Sex + 
        State * BCI + Month * Sex + Month * BCI + Sex * BCI, data = datum)
    >
    Residuals:
         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.23189 -0.03669  0.00000  0.05140  0.46119 
    >
    Coefficients:
                                          Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)                          -1.190830   3.287065  -0.362   0.7183   
    StateOklahoma                         1.268854   3.241452   0.391   0.6967  
    StateTexas                            0.923365   3.391279   0.272   0.7862  
    MonthJuly                             1.852632   3.306551   0.560   0.5771  
    MonthJune                             0.178968   0.631273   0.284   0.7777  
    MonthMay                              0.800204   0.742753   1.077   0.2852  
    SexMale                              -3.227029   1.806349  -1.786   0.0785 .
    BCI                                   4.492621  10.366883   0.433   0.6661  
    StateOklahoma:MonthJuly              -1.887727   3.311676  -0.570   0.5706  
    StateTexas:MonthJuly                 -1.376472   3.667010  -0.375   0.7086  
    StateOklahoma:MonthJune              -0.005473   0.185035  -0.030   0.9765  
    StateOklahoma:SexMale                 2.865873   1.697883   1.688   0.0961 .
    StateTexas:SexMale                    3.299948   2.155409   1.531   0.1305  
    MonthJuly:SexMale                     0.718199   0.973099   0.738   0.4631  
    MonthJune:SexMale                     0.959957   1.072644   0.895   0.3740  
    MonthMay:SexMale                      0.001622   0.123170   0.013   0.9895  
    StateOklahoma:BCI                    -3.686459  10.205038  -0.361   0.7191  
    StateTexas:BCI                       -3.389764  10.648608  -0.318   0.7512  
    MonthJuly:BCI                        -5.882602  10.425689  -0.564   0.5745  
    MonthJune:BCI                        -0.742253   2.015843  -0.368   0.7139  
    MonthMay:BCI                         -2.460383   2.094666  -1.175   0.2443  
    SexMale:BCI                          10.160989   5.780814   1.758   0.0834 .
    etc...
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    Residual standard error: 0.1041 on 67 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.4902,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2696 
    F-statistic: 2.222 on 29 and 67 DF,  p-value: 0.00375
```

Basically, I don't understand how to interpret the data in terms of the missing categorical variables in the reference group/intercept. I need to compare and report values for OK vs. NM vs. TX, May vs. June vs. July vs. August, and male vs. female. I've researched dummy coding but I can't find a solution that allows for a comparison across the board for all variables. I can only find dummy codes that compare one or two variables when I need up to three or four... How can I proceed if I need all of the information? I'm still learning what R has to offer!

Comment: At the moment the intercept is the predicted mean for a New Mexican woman with body concentration index zero in August so she does appear. Or is that not really what you are wondering about?